# SignalR Core Custom Authentication - Context.User.Identity is null after user is authenticated in /negotiate

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-signalr

I wrote a custom authentication for SignalR Core. One of the feature is anonymous login. It will create new user if it's first time user connect. The code work but the problem is the authentication done after */myhub/negotiate* is cleared and all the claims in **Context.User.Identity** is cleared again and IsAuthenticated change to false when the client request */myhub/*. Only after that the claims in **Context.User.Identity** is not cleared. I tried to return Fail if it's request to */myhub/negotiate* but then the client won't send request to */myhub/* if I do that.

Any idea on how to fix or work around this? Is my implement of custom authentication correct?

Here is the code of all the class I'm using:

```
public class CustomAuthRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CustomAuthRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CustomAuthRequirement requirement)
    {
        string name = context.User.Claims.Where(p => p.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Select(p => p.Value).SingleOrDefault();
        if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            context.Fail();
        else
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class CustomAuthRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{

}

public class MyAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<MyOptions>
{
    public MyAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<MyOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
    : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) { }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        if (Context.User.Identity != null && Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return await Task.FromResult(
                      AuthenticateResult.Success(
                         new AuthenticationTicket(
                             new ClaimsPrincipal(Options.Identity),
                             new AuthenticationProperties(),
                             this.Scheme.Name)));
        //if (Request.Path != "/myhub/") return await Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail()); // only do authentication in /myhub/
        var u = CreateNewUser(); // connect to db create new user
        var claims = new List<Claim>() { };
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, u.Id.ToString()));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, u.Id.ToString()));
        Options.Identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Custom");
        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(Options.Identity);
        Context.User = user;
        return await Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(user, new AuthenticationProperties(), this.Scheme.Name)));                        
    }

}

public class MyOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
    public ClaimsIdentity Identity { get; set; }

    public MyOptions()
    {

    }
}
```

The configuration code in ConfigureServices

```
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CustomAuthRequirementHandler>();
        services.AddAuthorization(p =>
        {
            p.AddPolicy("MainPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.Requirements.Add(new CustomAuthRequirement());
                builder.AuthenticationSchemes = new List<string> { "MyScheme" };
            });
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            o.DefaultScheme = "MyScheme";
        }).AddScheme<MyOptions, MyAuthenticationHandler>("MyScheme", "MyScheme", p => { });            
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddSignalR();
```

Configure code

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<Hubs.MainHub>("/main");
        });
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Edit: Added client side code

```
    @page
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<input type="button" onclick="anonLogin()" value="AnonLogin" />
<script src="~/@@aspnet/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var connection;    

    function anonLogin() {
        var token = "anon";
        connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/main?anon=" + token).build();        

        connection.start().then(function () {
            console.log("Connection ok");

            console.log("Sending message....");
            connection.invoke("Test").catch(function (err) {
                return console.error("Error sending message: " + err.toString());
            });
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Connection error: " + err.toString());
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The AddAuthentication statement should be called as first. Have you tried? And what about the Configure method?

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori I changed the order of AddAuthentication and AddAuthorization and the result is the same. I added the code in Configure to the question. I also change the part about the Context.User.Identity, this object is never null but after authentication in /negotiate all the claims in it are cleared and IsAuthenticated is false.

Comment: Can you add the client side code?

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori sure, just added them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a fake claims for identity just for the call to /myhub/negotiate since this call is unimportant and it just needs the authentication to success so it can go to /myhub/.

```
var u = new DomainUser() { Id = -1 };
        var claims = new List<Claim>() { };
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, u.Id.ToString()));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, u.Id.ToString()));
        Options.Identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Custom");
        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(Options.Identity);
        Context.User = user;
        return await Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(Context.User, new AuthenticationProperties(), this.Scheme.Name)));
```